# Web font ignores line-height or is mis-aligned

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, webfonts, line-height

We are building a new website and want to use some web fonts (hosted on fonts.google.com). We've done this in the past and did not have an issue (using OpenSans back then). We've settled for a different font this time (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Josefin+Sans).

But when I use the font, it looks like the text is mis-aligned compared to using the system font or sans-serif or basically any other font. It feels like the font is top-aligned within its text-box.

It should be centered vertically within the div by setting the line-height of the div to its height.

Am I imagining things? If not, is there a way to fix this? Either by some css-magic or by editing the font (although I have no idea how to do this).

I've created a codepen to illustrate my problem by copying the relevant styles from our website:  https://codepen.io/w00dy73/pen/mdewMNz

```
font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
```

(Stackoverflow tells me to put code next to the codepen link, but I'm not sure what the right code would be)

As requested, here is a screenshot of what it looks like to me (Firefox on Mac):

[image]
[image]
[image]

The black line represents the vertical center of the div and cuts the icon in half. In the top div, the text is not in half it's a bit top-heavy. In the bottom div the text is perfectly centered. The blue box is the outline of the texts box and the dotted lines are what Firefox shows me in the dev console when I inspect the elements. The text box of the top div is not aligned with the image (slight offset of 1-2px to the top) and the bottom works fine.

Comment: To me, it looks perfectly aligned, better than 'other div'. Can you post your screenshot?

Comment: Done. I've added a screenshot and some more explanation regarding my issue.

Comment: If the text contains `g` or `j` than the image would be different, right? Than top div text would be better aligned than bottom one. At the end you can set other line-height for the text and move the icon up or down.

Comment: I am talking about [this case](https://codepen.io/skobaljic/pen/NWGgwva) for example.

Comment: I've edited my codepen further and added an outline around the actual text. Either I'm going crazy or the text box of the top div is not aligned with the image. Although they are the same size and in the bottom example it works fine

Comment: We cannot judge how the font maker placed the icon line.... i'd suggest align the text and in case the icon is wrong, than just do position relative, top x, or margin-top x.... this is not a programming questions at all... cheers